# значение слова камарилья

Tags: этимология

Прошу разъяснить смысл и происхождение слова **камарилья**.

Answer (score 4):

**КАМАРИЛЬЯ**

> Заимств. в середине XIX в. из исп. яз., где camarilla — суф.
>   производное от camara «королевский двор» < «зал» (ср. придворный,
>   дворянин). Пейоративное (отрицательное) значение — вторично, ср.
>   банда, шайка.

Слово "камарилья" стало нарицательным и означает группу придворных, старающихся влиять на ход событий скрытыми интригами, наушничеством, доносами и т. п.

Слово имеет пометы: *книжное, собирательное, уничижительное*.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

То есть первичное современное значение слова - группа приближенных к власти людей, пытающихся влиять на ход событий скрытыми интригами. И вторичное - расширенное -  группа интриганов, доносчиков, пользующихся доверием власть имеющего лица, чтобы влиять на ход событий.

[ИСТОЧНИК](http://www.endic.ru/rusethy/Kamarilja-831.html)

Answer (score 2):

Камари́лья (исп. camarilla — «комнатка», «тайный кабинет») — так в Испании в 1814 называлась группа лиц, обычно собиравшихся в передней короля Фердинанда VII и оказывавших на него сильное влияние.